# Passing a semicolon as a parameter to a .bat file from both cmd and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, special-characters

This question seems to be rather simple, but even after searching the web for a couple of hours, I was not able to find a solution...

I have a batch file test.bat

```
set MY_VARIABLE=%~1
echo %MY_VARIABLE%
```

The point is that I want to call this programm with a semicolon as input parameter, i.e.,
`.\test.bat ";"`,
from both cmd and Windows PowerShell. While this works fine from cmd, PowerShell does not seem to get anything as an input. Is there any way to make this work for both simultaneously?

Comment: Where is the PowerShell code you are using?

Comment: I just want to start a powershell and type `.\test.bat ";"` so I don't have a PowerShell script, I want to start it from the prompt

Comment: Oh, well then I did not read carefully enough, sorry! Perhaps PowerShell expects `'` rather than `"`? or it does not like the `.\ `prefix, which is anyway not necessary?

Comment: No, unfortunately that does not change anything...

Comment: Hm… maybe try to replace `echo %MY_VARIABLE%` by `set MY_VARIABLE` in order to find out whether or not the variable becomes set as expected…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of [command line syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). The semicolon is one of multiple delimiters, that split the command line into words: `a;b` would be interpreted as two separate arguments `a` (`%1`) and `b` (`%2`).

Therefore, quotes are required. Since Powershell uses quotes for string literals (Powershell does its own re-quoting behind the scenes when passing arguments), you need to include them in the string:

```
.\test.bat '";"'
# or
.\test.bat "`";`""
```

Or as @mklement0 pointed out, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1) `--%` would also be an option:

```
.\test.bat --% ";"
```

Note that this is specific to Powershell syntax.

In CMD, this will suffice:

```
test.bat ";"
```

Comment: That solves the problem in PowerShell! Now the cmd version yields `'";"'` as the variable, but that can at least be handled... Thanks!

Comment: Powershell and cmd are different shells and have different syntax. There is now way around this. In cmd `test.bat ";"` will suffice.

Comment: More accurately, PowerShell performs - currently flawed - _re-quoting on demand_ behind the scenes, using double quotes. Since the verbatim string `;` contains no spaces, it passes it as-is, which breaks the batch-file call. if you added a space, e.g., `' ;'`, PowerShell would pass `" ;"`. You can control the exact command line used with the stop-parsing symbol, `--%`, but that comes with severe limitations: `.\test.bat --% ";"`.

Comment: PowerShell actually does the right thing in this case: a `;` should _not_ require quoting - `cmd.exe` has no business interpreting _batch-file arguments_ as if it were a `cmd.exe`-internal _command line_.